How to declare `Cow<'_, str>`.borrow() type in rust?
The code is the following:
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};

use std::fs::read;

use std::thread;

use std::borrow::Borrow;


fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) -> () {
   let mut buffer = [0; 4096];

   stream.read(&mut buffer).expect("read fail");

   let path_request = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]);
   println!("request \"{}\" received", path_request);

   let content_response = read(path_request.borrow()).unwrap();
   stream.write(&content_response).expect("response fail");
}

on compiling the next error is caused:
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:20:27
   |
20 |    let content_response = read(path_request.borrow()).unwrap();
   |                           ^^^^              ------ type must be known at this point
   |                           |
   |                           cannot infer type of the type parameter `P` declared on the function `read`

The question is how to declare the return type of borrowed Cow<'_, str>?

Typically you do so by adding an extra line with a defined type let borrowed_path_request: T = path_request.borrow();. You could do it in-line with a funky turbofish, but I try to avoid that because I find it difficult to read.

And what is T? Could you please explain?

That's the return type of the borrowed Cow :D

You can specify it on read.
let content_response = read::<&str>(path_request.borrow()).unwrap();

You can use a dereference instead of borrow, since that only has one type it can be (also &str).
let content_response = read(&*path_request).unwrap();

You can call borrow as a function.
let content_response = read(Borrow::<str>::borrow(&path_request)).unwrap();

Or you could make another variable.
let path: &str = path_request.borrow();
let content_response = read(path).unwrap();

Aside from this particular line, your code is unlikely to do what you want. stream.read only reads as much as is available at the time, so it can result in only part of the path in buffer. You need to handle the returned value to know how much of buffer has been written. If you want to read the entire message (until the TCP connection is closed), use read_to_end. If you want to read until some delimiter, then you'll need to either look for it manually in buffer, or wrap stream in BufReader and use BufRead::read_until.

It's <&str> in current case
the String::from_utf8_lossy() return type is Cow<'_, str> and Cow<'_, str>.borrow() return type is <&str>
So the code without on-compiling errors would be:
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};

use std::fs::read;

use std::thread;

use std::borrow::Borrow;


fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) -> () {
   let mut buffer = [0; 4096];

   stream.read(&mut buffer).expect("read fail");

   let path_request = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]);
   println!("request \"{}\" received", path_request);

   let content_response = read::<&str>(path_request.borrow()).unwrap();
   stream.write(&content_response).expect("response fail");
}

